# Join child values via XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I know my problem will be easily resolved if I have non-unique child nodes (by 'concat').

Problem:

```
<CarPlant>
      <Model>Audi</Model>
      <Model>Scoda</Model>
</CarPlant>
```

I would like to get a string e.g. "Audi,Scoda" to process it by scala's means.

Comment: @zx485 "concat(xpath,',',xpath)", of course it returns duplicated xpath, not the one combined

Comment: What XPath version do you use?

Comment: @zx485 Xpath 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
/CarPlant/string-join(Model,',')
```

will evaluate to

```
Audi,Scoda
```

for your XML, as requested.

Comment: I know that, for example, [this XPath tester](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) for some reason will accept such syntax, but AFAIK there is no such function as `fn:join`... Did you mean `fn:string-join`? Otherwise, can you provide any reference to `fn:join`? Thanks

Comment: @Andersson, yes, it should be `string-join()`.  Good catch.  Answer fixed.  Thank you.

Comment: [**array:join()**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-array-join) requires XPath 3.1.

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks a lot for the solution.